# PHP display product by category

Tags: php, arrays, json

What i want is to display all products that  below to category with id 1 in.
Is displaying all products but as well looping 3 times category with each products what i  want is to be .
one category with holder each and all product in each
here is my code:

```
$query_cat  = query("SELECT * FROM categories");
$query  = query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_category_id = '1'");
confirm($query_cat, $query);
$cat = fetch_array($query_cat);


while(($row = fetch_array($query))){
$category[] =   array(

        'category_id'=>$cat['cat_id'],
        'category_title'=>$cat['cat_title'],    
        
        'each' => $item[]  =    array (

        'product_id'=>$row['product_id'],
        'name'=>$row['product_title'],
        'product_tags'=>$row['product_category'],
        'partner_name_title'=>$row['partner_name_title'],
        'product_category_id'=>$row['product_category_id'],
        'image'=> $produc_img,
        'price'=>$row['product_price'],
        'discount'=>$row['product_discount'],
        'from_date'=>$row['start_discount'],
        'to_date'=>$row['finish_discount'],

        'sold'=>$row['counter_sold'],
        'desc'=>$row['product_about'],
        'location_address'=>$row['product_address'],
        'location'=>$row['product_location'],
        'partner_phone'=>$row['product_phone'],
        'partner_email'=>$row['product_email'],
        'partner_open_time'=>$row['product_open_time'],
        'partner_website'=>$row['product_website'],
        'instagram_page'=>$row['instagram_page'],
        'facebook_page'=>$row['facebook_page'],
        'product_prev'=>$row['product_prev'],
        'exp'=>$row['expire']

        )

    );
}

}
header("Content-Type: application/json");

echo json_encode(array('pro'=>$category), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
"pro": [
    {
        "category_id": "1",
        "category_title": "Food & Drink",
        "each": {
            "product_id": "84",
            "name": "Night Diner",
            "product_tags": "appetisers, food , health  food, amazing , good .",
            "partner_name_title": "Apantisi",
            "product_category_id": "1",
            "image": null,
            "price": "1",
            "discount": "-30%",
            "from_date": "2020-07-25",
            "to_date": "2020-12-25",
            "sold": "0",
            "desc": "Our restaurant proposing you to spend amazing  time with you family get the taste  of Caribbeans dishes   \r\nOur restaurant proposing you to spend amazing  time with you family get the taste  of Caribbeans dishes   \r\nOur restaurant proposing you to spend amazing  time with you family get the taste  of Caribbeans dishes   ",
            "location_address": "Glyfu 5 a",
            "location": "Nicosia",
            "partner_phone": "+357 97 832 983",
            "partner_email": "apantisi@gmail.com",
            "partner_open_time": "12:00-22:00",
            "partner_website": "www.apantisi.com.cy",
            "instagram_page": "instagram.com\/apantisi",
            "facebook_page": "facebook.com\/apantisi",
            "product_prev": "This coupon gives you discount -30%  on any reserved table in our restaurant .",
            "exp": "no"
        }
    },
    {
        "category_id": "1",
        "category_title": "Food & Drink",
        "each": {
            "product_id": "85",
            "name": "Princess Hair ",
            "product_tags": "hair , extensions hair, beauty , saloon   ",
            "partner_name_title": "Princess Hair",
            "product_category_id": "1",
            "image": null,
            "price": "1",
            "discount": "-50%",
            "from_date": "2020-07-25",
            "to_date": "2020-12-25",
            "sold": "2",
            "desc": "is the wonderful saloon hair for you we offer you best quality of hair  \r\nis the wonderful saloon hair for you we offer you best quality of hair  \r\nis the wonderful saloon hair for you we offer you best quality of hair  \r\nis the wonderful saloon hair for you we offer you best quality of hair  ",
            "location_address": " 1 Michail Georgalla Street",
            "location": "Nicosia",
            "partner_phone": "+357 97 832 983",
            "partner_email": "hair@gmail.com",
            "partner_open_time": "8:00-15:00 ",
            "partner_website": "www.hair.com.cy",
            "instagram_page": "instagram.com\/.hair",
            "facebook_page": "instagram.com\/.hair",
            "product_prev": "We offer you discount with -50% on our product bt code from coalaboom \/ use the chance to come with the code by  issue date ",
            "exp": "no"
        }
    }
```

but what i need is :

```
  "pro": [
    {
        "category_id": "1",
        "category_title": "Food & Drink",
        "each": {
            "product_id": "84",
            "name": "Night Diner",
            "product_tags": "appetisers, food , health  food, amazing , good .",
            "partner_name_title": "Apantisi",
            "product_category_id": "1",
            "image": null,
            "price": "1",
            "discount": "-30%",
            "from_date": "2020-07-25",
            "to_date": "2020-12-25",
            "sold": "0",
            "desc": "Our restaurant proposing you to spend amazing  time with you family get the taste  of Caribbeans dishes   \r\nOur restaurant proposing you to spend amazing  time with you family get the taste  of Caribbeans dishes   \r\nOur restaurant proposing you to spend amazing  time with you family get the taste  of Caribbeans dishes   ",
            "location_address": "Glyfu 5 a",
            "location": "Nicosia",
            "partner_phone": "+357 97 832 983",
            "partner_email": "apantisi@gmail.com",
            "partner_open_time": "12:00-22:00",
            "partner_website": "www.apantisi.com.cy",
            "instagram_page": "instagram.com\/apantisi",
            "facebook_page": "facebook.com\/apantisi",
            "product_prev": "This coupon gives you discount -30%  on any reserved table in our restaurant .",
            "exp": "no"
        },
       {
        "product_id": "85",
        "name": "Princess Hair ",
        "product_tags": "hair , extensions hair, beauty , saloon   ",
        "partner_name_title": "Princess Hair",
        "product_category_id": "1",
        "image": null,
        "price": "1",
        "discount": "-50%",
        "from_date": "2020-07-25",
        "to_date": "2020-12-25",
        "sold": "2",
        "desc": "is the wonderful saloon hair for you we offer you best quality of hair  \r\nis the wonderful saloon hair for you we offer you best quality of hair  \r\nis the wonderful saloon hair for you we offer you best quality of hair  \r\nis the wonderful saloon hair for you we offer you best quality of hair  ",
        "location_address": " 1 Michail Georgalla Street",
        "location": "Nicosia",
        "partner_phone": "+357 97 832 983",
        "partner_email": "hair@gmail.com",
        "partner_open_time": "8:00-15:00 ",
        "partner_website": "www.hair.com.cy",
        "instagram_page": "instagram.com\/.hair",
        "facebook_page": "instagram.com\/.hair",
        "product_prev": "We offer you discount with -50% on our product bt code from coalaboom \/ use the chance to come with the code by  issue date ",
        "exp": "no"
    }

    }
```

I want display product in each by category 1

Comment: how about replace `$cat = fetch_array($query_cat);` inside the while loop ?

Comment: yes  i dont kwow if is right to do this way

Comment: I tried this way still not right result

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `while` with:

```
$category = [
    'category_id'=>$cat['cat_id'],
    'category_title'=>$cat['cat_title'],
    'each' => [],
];
while(($row = fetch_array($query))){
    $category['each'][] = [
        'product_id'=>$row['product_id'],
        // ... rest of $row attributes
    ];
}
```

With this there will be one category and each product will have its entry in `each` key.